# Add a percentage text to a static Ionic 4 progress bar

Tags: css, progress-bar, ionic4

The [actual version](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/progress-bar) of the Ionic progress bar comes without an option to display the percentage text.

I tried to add it manually using the `::after` selector but to no avail.

This is my Ionic code:

```css
ion-progress-bar {
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ion-progress-bar color="success" value="0.9"></ion-progress-bar>
```

While inspecting the element this is what I get in chrome's elements inspector

```css
.progress, .progress-indeterminate {
    background: var(--progress-background);
    z-index: 2;
}

.buffer-circles, .indeterminate-bar-primary, .indeterminate-bar-secondary, .progress, .progress-buffer-bar, .progress-buffer-bar:before, .progress-indeterminate {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ion-progress-bar _ngcontent-c0="" color="success" value="0.9" ng-reflect-value="0.9" ng-reflect-color="success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0.9" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" class="ion-color ion-color-success progress-bar-determinate hydrated">
  #shadow-root
  <!-- ....... -->
  <div class="progress" style="transform: scaleX(0.9);"></div>
  <div class="progress-buffer-bar" style="transform: scaleX(1);"></div>
</ion-progress-bar>
```

The only way with which I can add a text from the elements inspector to the progress bar, is to add it inside the div with the `progress` class:

```
<div class="progress" style="transform: scaleX(0.9);">90%</div>
```

But adding this text from my Ionic code isn't possible, so I tried to use the `::after` selector but It did not work:

```
.progress:after{
  content: "90%";
}
```

I don't need that the text changes dynamically since the progress-bar must display a static value that does not change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what I was trying to achieve is impossible since it is a direct manipulation of the shadow dom.
Based on [this article](https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/), There are some key points concerning shadow dom:

> - You cannot style any of the internal elements of a web component from    outside of the web component using CSS selectors
> - You can style the internal elements of a web component if CSS4    variables are being used, as you can change the values of the CSS4 variables.
> - You can style slotted content inside of a web component (i.e. content    you have supplied to the web component) from outside of the web component
> - You can style the host element of the web component (i.e. the element    you use to add the web component to a page) from outside of the web component

Since there is no css4 variable or property that allows us to add a text value to the progress-bar, I had no choice but to use a [custom html progress bar](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-simple-progress-bar-component-in-ionic-2/):

```css
.progress-outer {
        width: 96%;
        margin: 10px 2%;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
}

.progress-inner {
        min-width: 15%;
        width: 90%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-inner">90%</div>
</div>
```

The appearance of the progress-bar can be then customized by changing the css properties

Answer (score 1):

simply you can put

```
ion-progress-bar {height:15px;}
```

in global.scss ..
if you also want to make the border radius then you can add the radius inside as well , as

```
ion-progress-bar {height:15px;border-radius:15px;}
```